# How to solve solve an ODE that depends on a strictly positive parameter?

Tags: differential-equations

To solve the ODE

```
f'' + f = 0 on (0, 1)
f(0) = f'(1) = 0.
```

I use the command

```
DSolve[{f''[x] + f[x] == 0, f[0] == 0, f'[1] == 0}, f[x], x]
```

Now I have an ODE depending an a constant `k > 0`

```
k * f'' + f = 0 on (0, 1)
f(0) = f'(1) = 0.
```

Could you elaborate on how to adjust above command to solve above parameter-dependent ODE? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is BVP with eigenvalue. The eigenvalue is $k$. Solution exist for specific values of $k$. DSolve does not take assumptions, so you have to post process the solution yourself.

```
sol = DSolve[{k*f''[x] + f[x] == 0, f[0] == 0, f'[1] == 0}, f[x], x];
sol = Assuming[k > 0, FullSimplify[sol]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
data = Table[{\[FormalN], Evaluate[sol]}, {\[FormalN], -3, 3}]
Grid[PrependTo[data, {"n", "solution"}], Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above says that for negative integer $n$ the solution is zero, and for positive $n$ solution is `C[1] Sin[x/Sqrt[k]]` but for specific values of $k$ as shown.

This is harder that the one you had before `f''[x] + f[x] == 0` because that did not have eigenvalue in it. So it was pure BVP ode. Adding the $k$ makes it an eigenvalue BVP, which are harder to solve.

Comment: And maybe worth noting for people who come across this, that you can use ParametricNDSolve for situations where you need numerical, non-symbolic, solutions.