# A problem when solving an ODE $-f'' + \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{k} \right )f=0$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I would like to solve an ODE $-f'' + \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{k} \right )f = 0$ on the interval $(0, 1)$ where $k \in (0, 1)$ is a constant. I use the command

```
sol = DSolve[{- f''[x] + (1 - 1 / k) * f[x] == 0}, f[x], {x, 0, 1}];
sol = Assuming[k > 0 && k < 1, FullSimplify[sol]]
```

Mathematica returns

[image]

The expression $\sqrt{\frac{-1+k}{k}}$ does not make sense to me because $\frac{-1+k}{k} < 0$ for $k \in (0, 1)$. Could you elaborate on this issue?

Comment: The expression makes mich sense, because `Sqrt[(-1+k)/k]->I /omega` transforms the ode in a well known form `omega^2 f''[x]+f[x]==0`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Could you explain what `Sqrt[(-1+k)/k]->I omega` means?

Comment: It's a simple substitution `Sqrt[(-1+k)/k]=:I omega `

Comment: You are using `DSolve` and not `NDSolve`. So writing `{x, 0, 1}` is not needed and does not do anything. Just write `x`. Do you know of a case where `DSolve` result was different when writing `{x,from,to}` vs. just `x`?  I know of no such case.

Comment: Could you show what output do you expect from the Simplify command other than the one Mathematica gave?

Comment: @Nasser I don't know the function `FullSimplify`. My command is actually taken from your [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/293821/64000). My ultimate goal is to have the solution in a form familiar to an undergraduate student.

Comment: To elaborate on what @UlrichNeumann said,$$e^{\pm \sqrt{(1-k)/k} x} = e^{\pm i \sqrt{(k-1)/k} x} = \cos \left( \sqrt{\frac{k-1}{k}} x \right) \pm i \sin \left( \sqrt{\frac{k-1}{k}} x \right)$$and if you choose complex values of $c_1$ and $c_2$ in your solution (specifically, $c_2 = c_1^*$) your solution becomes linear combination of a sine and a cosine.

Comment: @Nasser I get different answers with `DSolve[{y'[x] == Mod[x, 1]}, y, {x, 0, 4}]` and
`DSolve[{y'[x] == Mod[x, 1]}, y, x]`. Also with `DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x - 1], y[x /; x < 0] == x}, y, {x, 0, 4}]` and
`DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x - 1], y[x /; x < 0] == x}, y, x]`. And with some other DEs that have events.

Comment: @Goofy yes, good examples. But I am sure you know, these all can obtained from the general solution when using just $x$. I mean there is no magic here. There is only one solution. But I agree in these cases adding `{x,0,4}` Mathematica did a nice job in giving piecewise form of the solution which will be harder to obtain without extra work when just using $x$ only. So it is more convenient in this, I agree. I do not use events, but same concept apply. Mathematica can't generate new solution just because one say they want the solution from 0 to 4 only vs. for any x. But form can be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is the form you are looking for...?

```
sol = DSolve[{-f''[x] + (1 - 1/k)*f[x] == 0}, f[x], {x, 0, 1}];
sol = First[f[x] /. Assuming[k > 0 && k < 1, FullSimplify[sol]]];
PowerExpand[ExpToTrig[sol], Assumptions -> 0 < k < 1];
Collect[%, {Cos[_], Sin[_]}, Factor]
```

---

```
(C[1] + C[2]) Cos[Sqrt[-1 + 1/k] x] + I (C[1] - C[2]) Sin[Sqrt[-1 + 1/k] x]
```

$$(c_1+c_2) \cos \left(x \sqrt{\frac{1}{k}-1}\right)+i (c_1-c_2) \sin
   \left(x \sqrt{\frac{1}{k}-1}\right)$$

Comment: I meant to solve my ODE and present the solution in a familiar form. I could not see my ODE in your answer.

Comment: The `sol` is output of your code.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want the Trig solution to your problem

```
sol = DSolve[-f''[x] + (1 - 1/k) f[x] == 0, f[x], x] // Flatten
(* {f[x] -> C[1] E^((Sqrt[k - 1] x)/Sqrt[k]) + C[2] E^(-((Sqrt[k - 1] x)/Sqrt[k]))} *)
```

Convert the C's to forms we can manipulate and get the argument of the `Sqrt` positive based on your range of `k`

```
f[x_] = f[x] /. sol /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2, Sqrt[k - 1] -> I Sqrt[1 - k]}
(* c1 E^((I Sqrt[1 - k] x)/Sqrt[k]) + c2 E^(-((I Sqrt[1 - k] x)/Sqrt[k])) *)
```

Convert to trig form

```
ExpToTrig[f[x]] // Simplify
(* (c1 + c2) Cos[(Sqrt[1 - k] x)/Sqrt[k]] + I (c1 - c2) Sin[(Sqrt[1 - k] x)/Sqrt[k]] *)
```

And simplify the constants.

```
f[x_] = % /. {c1 + c2 -> c1, I (c1 - c2) -> c2}
(* c1 Cos[(Sqrt[1 - k] x)/Sqrt[k]] + c2 Sin[(Sqrt[1 - k] x)/Sqrt[k]] *)
```